# Sort column B while keeping column A's order

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel, I have 2 columns. I want to sort the second one in alphabetical order while keeping the (custom) order in the first one (think std::stable_sort where equality is  based on the first column only). Example:

```
dsf   k
www   d
www   a
azd   q
azd   e
azd   b
```

should become

```
dsf   k
www   a
www   d
azd   b
azd   e
azd   q
```

The sorting wizard doesn't seem to have any "keep current order" option. I could define the custom order but I have more than a thousand different elements; that would be a real pain to do and this custom order can change at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll assume that your data start in Row 2, and that Column `C` is available for use as a “helper column”.  Put

```
=IF(A1=A2, C1, C1+1)
```

into cell `C2`.  (If Column `C` isn’t available, use one that is. 
If your data start in Row 1, either insert a blank row,
or (still) put the above into cell `C2`, but put `1` into cell `C1`.) 
Drag/fill down. 
This (Column `C`) now “documents” your custom order;
e.g., `C2` = 1,`C3` = `C4` = 2, and`C5` = `C6` = `C7` = 3. 
Now sort on Column `C` and Column `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use custom orders.  If it doesn't have to be updated to often you could do it through `FILE>OPTIONS>ADVANCED>EDIT CUSTOM LISTS...` and just import the entire range.  Then use that when sorting.

VBA solution would be something like

```
Sub sort()
Dim iCustListNum As Integer

iCustListNum = Application.CustomListCount + 1
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Range("A2:A100")

On Error GoTo err:

'Sort your list
Range("A1:B100").sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, OrderCustom:=iCustListNum, _
    Key2:=Range("B1"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
    MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

'Clean up
err:
Application.DeleteCustomList ListNum:=iCustListNum

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:-

1. Copy the contents of column A into notepad, then recopy to the clipboard.
2. Select both columns.
3. Select the sort function and sort column A using the "custom list" order.
4. Enter the data from the clipboard into the custom list.
5. Add a level to the sort function and then sort by column B, "smallest to largest".