# Excel sort dates to be in oldest to newest without changing grouping

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, sorting, date

I have a list of customers with due dates and corresponding payment dates but the payment dates weren't updated in the correct order. Is there a way I can sort the payment date to be in order without changing the order of the customer and their original due dates? Either thru a look up that can get the dates in order or thru a macro. I've tried using a large on index match but was unsuccessful. Any help would be great!

[Data set looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Y8W.png)

```
CUSTOMER, DUE DATE, PAYMENT DATE

Toni,     1-Jan 17, 17-Mar-17
Toni,    16-Jan 17,  2-Mar-17
Toni,    31-Jan-17,  1-Jan-17
Toni,    15-Feb-17,  1-Apr-17
Rr,       7-Jan-17, 15-Feb-17
Rr,      22-Jan-17, 16-Jan-17
Rr,       6-Feb-17, 31-Jan-17
```

[End result should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE1ey.png)

```
CUSTOMER, DUE DATE, PAYMENT DATE
Toni,     1-Jan 17,  1-Jan-17
Toni ,   16-Jan 17,  2-Mar-17
Toni ,   31-Jan-17, 17-Mar-17
Toni ,   15-Feb-17,  1-Apr-17
Rr,       7-Jan-17, 16-Jan-17
Rr,      22-Jan-17, 31-Jan-17
Rr,       6-Feb-17, 15-Feb-17
```

Apologies in advance for the poor formatting as I'm still new.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort column B while keeping column A's order](https://superuser.com/questions/682225/sort-column-b-while-keeping-column-as-order)

Answer (score 1):

I think your 'after' is wrong based on your question, but I have answered with what I think you're trying to get to.

You need to highlight the column with your incorrect dates in, go to the Data tab on the ribbon and sort A>Z, and at the 'Sort Warning' dialog select 'Continue with the current selection'

[image]

The result will be that the data in columns A and B will remain as they are now, and column C will be re-ordered.

Comment: Hi, yes understand that I can do that manually per group but is there a way to do it by bulk as in my database I have 2k plus groups. Thanks!

Comment: select header row > goto data, filter > click on any drop down selection , sort by color, custom filter > set the sorting/grouping criteria. > Done. ( :

Answer (score 0):

@Spikey_Richie's answer above looks mostly correct, although you'll need to do this in groups for each user above.

I suspect the way that this has come about is by doing a sort with Autofilter set up, but not including the final column.

I would suggest going back to the original data (pre-sorting) and re-sort it, making sure that the whole set is ordered.

As it stands, the only way we can know what the correct value for the final column is, is by the fact that you've told us in the question.  There would be no way of us knowing this (for sure) otherwise.  We would have to make assumptions that may or may not be true.

Comment: Hi, it needs to be that per person / group, the dates need to be in chronological order. I've tried the custom sort w/ 2 levels but it doesn't because even after sorting the paid date column then sorting the due date column it just goes back to the original data set. Thanks!